# How do I iterate through this data in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to iterate through all of the objects stored in "testmaps".

I've tried just iterating through the "testmaps" as a starting point, but it seems like I am iterating through strings rather than maps when I do so. Therefore, I cannot access the objects within.

JSON

```
{"testmap1":

[{"name":"testObject1","boolean1":true,"boolean2":true,"boolean3":false,"otherString":"test"},
{"name":"testObject2","boolean1":false,"boolean2":false,"boolean3":false,"otherString":"test2"}],

"testmap2":

[{"name":"testObject3","boolean1":false,"boolean2":false,"boolean3":false,"otherString":"test3"},
{"name":"testObject4","boolean1":false,"boolean2":true,"boolean3":false,"otherString":"test4"}]}
```

TypeScript where I read in the data:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.http.get('http://myURL').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.array = data;
        console.log(this.array);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

TypeScript; I tried to iterate like this:

```
ngDoCheck(){

    for (let map in this.array) {
      for (let item in map.valueOf){
        console.log(item.otherString);
      }
    }
  }
```

The loop I tried doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (let item in data)` is used to loop through properties in an object. This will loop through the object properties and each iteration will return a key in that object. For an array though you can use `forEach()` to loop through each element in the array.

```js
let data = {
  "testmap1":

    [{
        "name": "testObject1",
        "boolean1": true,
        "boolean2": true,
        "boolean3": false,
        "otherString": "test"
      },
      {
        "name": "testObject2",
        "boolean1": false,
        "boolean2": false,
        "boolean3": false,
        "otherString": "test2"
      }
    ],

  "testmap2":

    [{
        "name": "testObject3",
        "boolean1": false,
        "boolean2": false,
        "boolean3": false,
        "otherString": "test3"
      },
      {
        "name": "testObject4",
        "boolean1": false,
        "boolean2": true,
        "boolean3": false,
        "otherString": "test4"
      }
    ]
};

for (let testmap in data) {
  data[testmap].forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.otherString);
  });
}
```